# Can't start bounty for my question

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786582/options-menu-poping-out-in-all-activities-inside-activity-group). Now I thought of starting an bounty for it, but I can't see any start a bounty option for my question. But it is visible for my other questions. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your answer is here: [Frequently Asked Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

> There are a few other rules around bounties:
>
> •**Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.**
>
> •Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
>
> •There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any
> given time.
>
> •Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
>
> •After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
>
> •If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted
> answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will
> be awarded half the bounty amount.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait two days before you can add a bounty. Please see [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for more information.